# MapStruct undefined method call

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a given scenario like below

```
class Curve {
      private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

      public List<Point> getPoint() {
       this.points;
      }
      
      public void addPoint(Point point) {
       this.point.add(point);
      }
  }
```

The mapper class is like below :

```
@Mapper
public interface CurveMapper {

CurveMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CurveMapper.class);

com.entity.Curve mapTo(com.dto.Curve);

}
```

MapStruct auto generates CurveMapperImpl class like below :

```
public class CurveMapperImpl implements CurveMapper {
       
@Override
public com.entity.Curve mapTo(com.dto.Curve curve) {    
     if (curve == null) {
       return null;
     }

     com.entity.Curve curve1 = new com.entity.Curve();
     for(com.dto.Point point : curve) {
        curve1.add(convertPoint(point));
     } 
}
```

mapStruct by default looks for **`curve.add()`** method but the target class has **`curve.addPoint()`**. Therefore it is failing.

How can I ask mapStruct to look for **`curve.addPoint()`** as I cannot modify the target class structure?

Comment: Could you please share mapStruct code?

Comment: where is this method defined in your mapper mapTo()? you have not posted your complete code

Comment: I have edited the question. mapTo method is inside mapper class

Comment: **`CurveMapperImpl`** is the mapStruct generated class. The only method I haven't posted is `convertPoint(point)` which is plain setter/getter calls on Point class fields.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```java
@Mapper( collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED )
public interface CurveMapper {

CurveMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CurveMapper.class);

com.entity.Curve mapTo(com.dto.Curve);

}
```